# C# Regex String Array escape *

Tags: c#, regex, string, escaping

I have this string Array of file extensions:

```
public string[] mimeArray = new string[] { "text / plain", @"text / htmlmultipart/.*", "application/octet-stream", @"application/.*", @"text/.*", @"image/.*", @"audio/.*", @"video/.*" };};
```

My Regex are not working properly, it's taking:

```
"text / plain", 
"text / htmlmultipart\\", 
"application/octet-stream",
 "application\\", 
"text\\", 
"image\\", 
"audio\\", 
"video\\"
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I need my array to take like:

```
image/*
```

to compare with files extensions like `image/png`

I have a for each loop with file attachments, I save the extension in a local var:

```
var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(item.Name);
```

And then I need to validate if the extension exists on the array declared. I use this method:

```
private bool ValidateMime(string mimeType)
        {
            if(mimeArray.Contains(mimeType))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Could anybody help me correct my Array?

Comment: have you tried `image/\\*`

Comment: I just tried it but It's not working either. I also tried with a @ at the beginning

Comment: Show us the Regexes you tried.

Comment: `"\*"` is not a valid string literal. Please post the real code, the whole relevant code, in the question. Your issue is in the code that is missing.

Comment: I believe what you try is to translate the mime filters to regex pattern, e.g. `image\*` -> `^image\\.*$`

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `mimeArray` was an string `array` so It will always take the string as a literal.

The workaround was to create the array as a `Regex array` like below:

```
 private Regex[] mimeArray = new[] {
            new Regex(@"^text\/plain"),
            new Regex(@"text\/html"),
            new Regex(@"^multipart\/.*"),
            new Regex(@"^application\/octet-stream"),
            new Regex(@"^application\/.*$"),
            new Regex(@"^text\/.*$"),
            new Regex(@"^image\/.*$"),
            new Regex(@"^audio\/.*$"),
            new Regex(@"^video\/.*$")
        };
```

and then modify the comparer method:

```
private bool ValidateMime(string mimeType)
        {
            if(mimeArray.Any(x => x.IsMatch(mimeType)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Thanks everyone who took the time to help me on this. And I hope this helps anybody also.

Answer (score 0):

According to regex tester like [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester), the pattern

```
(image/[*])
```

or if you don't need to mark the whole word

```
image/[*]
```

will match your request of input

```
image/*
```

Comment: This brings me literally the [*]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ehsan, `"image\*"` will match anything after "image"

You might try `@"image/.*"` since the .NET regex engine needs the `".*"` syntax. Bash scripts and other regex engines can use the naked wildcard `*`, but .NET is different.

String literals (the `@"text"` code) allow you to put special characters inside your strings without needing to escape them a bunch. [See MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: This is taking correctly the value like image/.* but when I compare with Image/png it's returning false

Comment: @pedrodotnet Regex can *match* a string, it does not "take" anything. Regex cannot return true or false, a regex method can. Please update the question.

Comment: pedro, did you mean to capitalize the `Image/png`? If so, make sure the regex operation is case insenstive.